# How to reduce space b/w bars in group bar chart D3 v4

Tags: javascript, d3.js

Using D3 v4 to create charts.I found this sample grouped chart on internet. It was using d3 v3 so i converted it in D3 v4. 
Now i want to reduce the space b/w bars in group bar chart. How can i do this?

I want to place bars side by side. there should not be space between bars. they should be adjacent to each other.

link of codepen - https://codepen.io/pinkisharma/pen/OEOdRw

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>

body {
  font: 10px sans-serif;
}

.axis path,
.axis line {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #000;
  shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}

.x.axis path {
  display: none;
}

</style>
<body>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<script>

var data = [
    {
        "categorie": "Student", 
        "values": [
            {
                "value": 0, 
                "rate": "Not at all"
            }, 
            {
                "value": 4, 
                "rate": "Not very much"
            }, 
            {
                "value": 12, 
                "rate": "Medium"
            }, 
            {
                "value": 6, 
                "rate": "Very much"
            }, 
            {
                "value": 0, 
                "rate": "Tremendously"
            }
        ]
    }, 
    {
        "categorie": "Liberal Profession", 
        "values": [
            {
                "value": 1, 
                "rate": "Not at all"
            }, 
            {
                "value": 21, 
                "rate": "Not very much"
            }, 
            {
                "value": 13, 
                "rate": "Medium"
            }, 
            {
                "value": 18, 
                "rate": "Very much"
            }, 
            {
                "value": 6, 
                "rate": "Tremendously"
            }
        ]
    }, 
    {
        "categorie": "Salaried Staff", 
        "values": [
            {
                "value": 3, 
                "rate": "Not at all"
            }, 
            {
                "value": 22, 
                "rate": "Not very much"
            }, 
            {
                "value": 6, 
                "rate": "Medium"
            }, 
            {
                "value": 15, 
                "rate": "Very much"
            }, 
            {
                "value": 3, 
                "rate": "Tremendously"
            }
        ]
    }, 
    {
        "categorie": "Employee", 
        "values": [
            {
                "value": 12, 
                "rate": "Not at all"
            }, 
            {
                "value": 7, 
                "rate": "Not very much"
            }, 
            {
                "value": 18, 
                "rate": "Medium"
            }, 
            {
                "value": 13, 
                "rate": "Very much"
            }, 
            {
                "value": 6, 
                "rate": "Tremendously"
            }
        ]
    }, 
    {
        "categorie": "Craftsman", 
        "values": [
            {
                "value": 6, 
                "rate": "Not at all"
            }, 
            {
                "value": 15, 
                "rate": "Not very much"
            }, 
            {
                "value": 9, 
                "rate": "Medium"
            }, 
            {
                "value": 12, 
                "rate": "Very much"
            }, 
            {
                "value": 3, 
                "rate": "Tremendously"
            }
        ]
    }, 
    {
        "categorie": "Inactive", 
        "values": [
            {
                "value": 6, 
                "rate": "Not at all"
            }, 
            {
                "value": 6, 
                "rate": "Not very much"
            }, 
            {
                "value": 6, 
                "rate": "Medium"
            }, 
            {
                "value": 2, 
                "rate": "Very much"
            }, 
            {
                "value": 3, 
                "rate": "Tremendously"
            }
        ]
    }
];
var margin = {top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 30, left: 40},
    width = 960 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

var x0 = d3.scaleBand()
    .rangeRound([0, width], .1);

var x1 = d3.scaleBand();

var y = d3.scaleLinear()
    .range([height, 0]);

var xAxis = d3.axisBottom(x0)
    .tickSize(0);

var yAxis = d3.axisLeft(y);
var color = d3.scaleOrdinal()
    .range(["#ca0020","#f4a582","#d5d5d5","#92c5de","#0571b0"]);

var svg = d3.select('body').append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

data.forEach(function(d) {

  var categoriesNames = data.map(function(d) { return d.categorie; });
  var rateNames = data[0].values.map(function(d) { return d.rate; });

  x0.domain(categoriesNames);
  x1.domain(rateNames).range([0, x0.bandwidth()]);
  y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(categorie) { return d3.max(categorie.values, function(d) { return d.value; }); })]);

  svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "x axis")
      .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
      .call(xAxis);

  svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "y axis")
      .style('opacity','0')
      .call(yAxis)
  .append("text")
      .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
      .attr("y", 6)
      .attr("dy", ".71em")
      .style("text-anchor", "end")
      .style('font-weight','bold')
      .text("Value");

  svg.select('.y').transition().duration(500).delay(1300).style('opacity','1');

  var slice = svg.selectAll(".slice")
      .data(data)
      .enter().append("g")
      .attr("class", "g")
      .attr("transform",function(d) { return "translate(" + x0(d.categorie) + ",0)"; });

  slice.selectAll("rect")
      .data(function(d) { return d.values; })
  .enter().append("rect")
      .attr("width", 10)
      .attr("x", function(d) { return x1(d.rate); })
      .attr('dy', '0.32em')
      .style("fill", function(d) { return color(d.rate) })
      .attr("y", function(d) { return y(0); })
      .attr("height", function(d) { return height - y(0); })
      .on("mouseover", function(d) {
          d3.select(this).style("fill", d3.rgb(color(d.rate)).darker(2));
      })
      .on("mouseout", function(d) {
          d3.select(this).style("fill", color(d.rate));
      });

  slice.selectAll("rect")
      .transition()
      .delay(function (d) {return Math.random()*1000;})
      .duration(1000)
      .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d.value); })
      .attr("height", function(d) { return height - y(d.value); });

  //Legend
  var legend = svg.selectAll(".legend")
      .data(data[0].values.map(function(d) { return d.rate; }).reverse())
  .enter().append("g")
      .attr("class", "legend")
      .attr("transform", function(d,i) { return "translate(0," + i * 20 + ")"; })
      .style("opacity","0");

  legend.append("rect")
      .attr("x", width - 18)
      .attr("width", 18)
      .attr("height", 18)
      .style("fill", function(d) { return color(d); });

  legend.append("text")
      .attr("x", width - 24)
      .attr("y", 9)
      .attr("dy", ".35em")
      .style("text-anchor", "end")
      .text(function(d) {return d; });

  legend.transition().duration(500).delay(function(d,i){ return 1300 + 100 * i; }).style("opacity","1");

});

</script>
```

Comment: Also,I want to add tool tip on this chart.

Comment: In your case you'd just add width to your slice variable and add `.padding(0.1)` to the `x0` variable, but hardcoding the width is not a good way to go about it, I'd start with Mike Bostocks [example](https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3887051) and add feauters you'd like to that.

Comment: @PinkiSharma please, keep it just **one** issue per question. Also, please mind that *"I want to add tool tip on this chart"* is quite broad, and it will be closed as such: instead of that, show us what you tried to add the tooltip, and what went wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While upgrading to v4, you kept a v3 pattern in the range:

```
.rangeRound([0, width], .1)
//this won't work--------^
```

While that defined the padding in v3, that's not the way to define the padding in a v4 band scale. For that, you have to use `padding`. For instance, with `0.5`:

```
.padding(0.5).
```

Here is the update codepen: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/BVmMGb?editors=0010

Comment: Thanks @Gerardo Furtado for providing solution. This is what i have done for tooltip - https://codepen.io/pinkisharma/pen/JZOqgO . but i want legend name instead of "val" in tooltip. As of now in all bars, its coming like this - val : x but i want legend name in place of "val"